# Can not login into my grails application

Tags: security, authentication, grails

i have a grails application in which bootstrap.groovy file i am creating to user one admin and another normal user.
i am using spring security plugin for security.

my problem is i am able to login from user created in bootstrap.groovy bt while i am creating a new user from my application i am not able to login from that user.

i am getting the following error message :

```
DEBUG dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
```

here is my domain encode password function

```
def beforeInsert() {

        super.beforeInsert()
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }
protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
```

here is my user insertion code values coming from my login form

```
User user = User.findByEmail(email) ?: new User(firstName: fname, lastName: lname, email: email,
                password: password, enabled: true, accountLocked: false, accountExpired: false).save()
```

here is my bootstrap.groovy inIt function

```
User user = User.findByEmail('systemuser@gmail.com') ?: new User(firstName: 'System', lastName: 'User', email: 'systemuser@gmail.com',
                password: 'user', enabled: true, accountLocked: false, accountExpired: false).save()
```

i am using this password algorithm for encoding

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm='bcrypt'
```

Comment: how do you create that user? how do you set password, in particular? do you use `passwordEncoder`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov i have updated my ques with the details u might b asking for

Comment: @IgorArtamonov when i click submit in my form i alerted my password textbox value it is coming like [object Object].

Comment: Your code snippet suggest that your User class inherit from a base class.  How is that class? What is your spring security plugin configuration?  Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: @Fernando  i got ma problem solved. the error was in my javascript. the value was being passed as a object so that object was being considered as a string and encoded as a password. now the code is working fine. thanks all for your support....  :)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov i got ma problem solved. the error was in my javascript. the value was being passed as a object so that object was being considered as a string and encoded as a password. now the code is working fine. thanks all for your support....  :)